# How to show Pointer in non-browser field

Tags: blackberry

I have a blackberry application in which I want to use pointer navigation, just like the browser field, however I do not want to use a browserfield. On the surface it seems like it would be simple however I am having trouble finding out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlackBerry standard interface does not provide a pointer. Focus moves from one input UI element to the next depending on the navigation interface which could be 1 dimensional (scroll wheel), 2 dimensional, or multi-touch.

If you want to provide a pointer based navigation model you will have to write your own UI toolkit.